# Return row that contains the highest value in a Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a data set of quotations that our company has raised that I'm doing some analysis on. I've got a column for the largest quotation we've done for each client by using *Summarise Values by* > *Max*, but I would really like to include which specific quotation has that value (each quotation has a name; one of my columns in my data). Here is [my field arrangement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJvaz.png) if that helps.

To complicate things slightly, the data is split between *Last 90 Days* and *Previous 90 Days*, so there will be a max value for each of those. (I have a calculation in the original data that returns "Last 90 Days" or "Previous 90 Days" as a text field so I can apply filters and slicers to my pivot). So any solution needs to take this extra field into account.

Honestly, I've tried so many things at this point; the closest I got was using Power Query to group columns and then loading that as a pivot table into the worksheet, but I couldn't quite it there. I can't seem to find any solution that fits exactly what I'm wanting.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help.

(And please be gentle, I'm new!)

Edit:

This is an example of the kind of thing I'm after; it's just the last column in the pivot output that I'm struggling with.

Sample Data:

| Quote Name | Client | Quote Value | Last 90 or Previous 90 Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2300 Site 1 | Client 1 | 26950 | Previous 90 Days |
| 2301 Site 2 | Client 2 | 11450 | Previous 90 Days |
| 2302 Site 3 | Client 3 | 19500 | Previous 90 Days |
| 2303 Site 4 | Client 1 | 24550 | Previous 90 Days |
| 2304 Site 5 | Client 2 | 33450 | Previous 90 Days |

Pivot Table Output:

| Client | # of Quotes | Total Value | Average Value | Largest Value | Largest Quote |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Client 1 | 43 | £286,775 | £6,669 | £26,950 | 2300 Site 1 |
| Client 2 | 28 | £201,050 | £6,485 | £33,450 | 2304 Site 5 |

Also, I have a slicer on the data to filter between Last 90 days and Previous 90 Days, but this could be changed to a filter on the table if it helps with the solution.

Edit 2:
[Here is a screenshot of my pivot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiyIk.png), if it helps.

Comment: I think you need to show sample data and desired output.  It is not clear what you are after.  Please dont post a picture of it, post it as text.

Comment: @RohitGupta yeah that's fair, I've edited my post with an example. Hope that helps.

Comment: Please clarify your request a bit further - your sample data suggests that you only want the top two quotes, or did you just break it off at that point? If so, you can easily get the top two (or any other number) through a pivottable, and sumif/averageif/countif the rest of your fields.

Comment: Hi @Paul, sorry no that's just where I cut off the sample. There are 585 quotations in the raw data, with a total of 83 unique clients.

Comment: This is most certainly not doable with a Pivot Table. It can be easily done with Power Query. This site has a Power Query solution for more or less exactly your use case: https://gorilla.bi/power-query/using-table-max/. Adding an the row "Details" with "All Rows" is the crucial step and then using Table.Max on that column.

Comment: Thanks @Hubisan for confirming my suspicions regarding not being able to achieve this with a pivot table. And thank you for the potential solution, I'll look into implementing that :)